# How to 'remember' a site member's last visited page?

Tags: php, users, session, bookmark

I've seen this on a couple of sites - they offer a multipage tutorials to site members.  When you return to the site, they have a link that takes to the last page of the tutorial you were on.  How is this accomplished?  Guessing it has something to do with the PHP session?

Comment: If you want to do it for registered members only then you can simple add last URL as user meta value in WordPress database. [add_user_meta] (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) But if you also want this feature for guest visitors too then use cookie. Store last visited URL in browser cookie.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely for registered members only.  However, I would like to limit it to specific content types.  So if there in the middle of a tutorial, that is what they have an easy link back to.  Instead of the precise last page they visited (like their profile, the home page, etc).